# Is Socket.IO4Net On method blocking?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, socket.io

So I am working in an existing code base where they are using SocketIO4Net alot to communicate with "the web".

And with SocketIO you are using events to pass messages like:

```
m_mySocket.On("myMessageFromTheWeb", m_endpoint, (data) =>
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

I have understood (I think) that this will be handled asynchronously as in it will not block my main context thread. But my question is: is it blocking the socket thread in any way? If my code instead was:

```
m_mySocket.On("myMessageFromTheWeb", m_endpoint, (data) =>
{
    DoTimeConsumingStuff();
}
```

Would I then be able to receive any other calls or am I in a sense blocking the receiving thread until I return?